# C programming structure passed as cast to char *?

Tags: c

I have a little problem, in a scenario where:

```
while (read(dp->fd, (char *) &dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf)) == sizeof(dirbuf)) { ... }
```

where dirbuf is:

```
struct direct dirbuf { 
    ino_t d_ino; char d_name[DIRSIZ]; 
};
```

How does C know to read in data contingently into our structure? With the read() Like, the alignment of our dirbuf fits perfectly as a character array? since read accepts a void * for its second argument, passing a structure as a cast to char * makes very little sense to me, how does it cater for other member elements properly?

I'm not sure if I'm even asking this question properly, I hope someone can decipher my problem behind my lunacy and help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Over and above what Digital Ross points out, the 'struct direct' you show is for the old Unix file system - the one that limited names to 14 characters.  You can't, in general, read a directory using 'read()' on modern versions of Unix (Linux, MacOS X); you have to use the opendir(), readdir() family of functions and 'struct dirent'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler does the `while` condition mean that the number of character `read` should always be equal to the structure size? isn't there a high probability that it could be false most of the time?

Comment: @noufal: it depends on the context in which you are working. On a modern O/S, the read will fail; you can't use `read()` to read a file descriptor that has a directory open. (You can use such a file descriptor for the `fchdir()` system call and maybe the `*at()` system calls.) In the old days when the UFS meant the 14-character maximum file name length, the `read()` shown would return 16 reliably each time until it reached EOF, when it would return 0, of course. In the not quite so old days, trying to read a FFS (Berkeley 'Fast File System'), you'd run into problems because the names varied.

Answer (score 6):

#### Hysterical Raisens

Casting buffers to `char *` is a legacy code pattern that one sees frequently. It has been used so often that it is still typed in today, long after it ceased to be necessary.

At one point there was no `void` type, so an API like `read(2)` would declare the buffer parameter as `char *` and all callers would cast their data *to* `char *`.

But `read(2)` has been a `void *` for a long, long, time. It has been that long since it was necessary to have any kind of a cast at the call site.

However, the old code is still around, people still read it, and then they perpetuate the design pattern.

It doesn't do any harm.

With respect to contiguous data, one of two things is happening. Either the data structure and the type is designed to lay out densely on most or all likely machines, or a similar statement was used to write the data out in the first place so pad bytes don't matter unless the data file is to be moved between disparate architectures.

Comment: To add to DigitalRoss' history of using `char*` or `void*` as the generic pointer type, remember that you can safely cast any pointer to and from type `void*` without losing any data.  That is why code like this that still uses `char*` works without requiring changes.

Comment: @bta: you can actually do the same thing (casting without loss of data) with `char *` as the standard requires `char *` and `void *` to have identical representations; there are some differences between `void *` and `char *`, though: you can't do arithmetics with the former and there's no automatic conversion to and from the latter

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't read and properly align the fields in the structure. It just takes the total size of the structure (from `sizeof`) and the starting address (from `&dirbuf`) and reads into that memory without regard to the struct declaration.

The assumption is that whatever was in the file was *already* properly aligned to fit in the structure.

The `(char *)` cast is just there to shut the compiler up.  `(void *)` would have done just as well. Or no cast at all, since the compiler will convert pointer type to void* without casting.

Comment: In fact, in modern times no cast at all is needed there.  The cast is a hangover from pre-ANSI-C days, when there was no `void *` (and thus UNIXes of the time defined the second argument of `read` as `char *`).

Answer (score 0):

This must be a nod to archaic versions of C langauage, which didn't have `void *` type and used `char *` instead. If you are using a non-archaic compiler and the parameter is indeed `void *`, there's no need to cast anything to `char *` (and there's no need to cast anything to `void *` either)

```
read(dp->fd, &dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf))
```

And C does not know and does not need to know how to read the data into your specific structure. When you do something like the above, the binary data from the file is blindly read into the raw memory occupied by your `dirbuf` object. If the layout of that binary data is correct (for example, if the file was created by writing the same structure in the same way), then everything will be aligned properly and everything will automatically fall into its proper place.

Note, that unless you are working with something that is covered by a very strict specification, such a straighforward binary write/read techniques are only useable within a single session of the same program, or maybe between different sessions of the same version of the program on the same platform. Once you start dealing with different platforms and/or different versions of the code on the same platform, thing can easily fall apart once the raw memory layout of the data changes.